# Cancelling Axios request in React when using React Router Switch

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm a newbie building an App that utilizes React Router to switch between 3 different components that each utilize Axios to fetch data from an API. I am trying to cancel the API request whenever a navlink is clicked to prevent the "Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function" error in console. First I tried using AbortController in the App.js where the links are by adding click events that utilized controller.abort();. When that didn't work I tried directly where Axios was being called(seen in DisplayFish.js in my code sandbox example below) and still no luck. I have a simplified version of the main page with links and 1 of the components to show my code here https://codesandbox.io/s/white-voice-s8moo?file=/src/App.js    Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use cancel axios request using axios.CancelToken.

```
const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();

axios.get('/user/12345', {
  cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token
});

// Cancel request
cancelTokenSource.cancel();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I tried it out and am still getting the memory leak warning, I think I am not understanding exactly where to cancel the request. I've updated my code in DisplayFish.js to be 
const cancelTokenSource = axios.CancelToken.source();
    const url = window.location.pathname;
  function getFish(){if( url === '/'){axios.get(apiURL, {cancelToken: cancelTokenSource.token}).then(showFish)}
else{cancelTokenSource.cancel();}}

and also tried it with the click function in app.js with no luck.

Comment: I was able to figure it out by using the cancel request in a useEffect cleanup function, thank you again for your help!